# calling settings.py from another python scripts

Tags: python, dotenv

I have .env file where I have added environment settings. I wrote "settings.py" which reads .env file and stores values of settings. I want to import settings.py from other_script.py. But I am getting None as value.

I tried to execute "settings.py" and returns a value. On the other hand when I execute other_script which imports settings, the values become None value.

settings.py:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path


env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(env_path)

MONGO_IP = os.getenv("MONGO_IP")
MONGO_PORT = os.getenv("MONGO_PORT")
MONGO_DB = os.getenv("MONGO_DB")

print(MONGO_DB)
```

other_script.py:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from settings import MONGO_IP, MONGO_PORT, MONGO_DB

print(MONGO_DB)

mongo_client = MongoClient(MONGO_IP, MONGO_PORT)[MONGO_DB]
```

So when I execute other_script.py, keys should return a value. What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check are:

1. `settings.py` and `other_script.py` are in the same folder. Without this, `other_script.py` will not be able to find `settings.py`.
2. Look at your `env` and see if `load_dotenv(env_path)` is working properly. If env values for `MONGO_*` are not set properly you cannot read them.

Comment: 1. They are not in the same folder. 2. They work properly when executing settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

If they are not in the same folder, the issue perhaps is that you don't have an `__init__.py` file in the folder you want to import from, since it is needed to make it a package. The init file can be empty.